# InputTouchHelper background layer is non-clickable

Tags: java, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-service

[image]This is my first time working with `ItemTouchHelper`, maybe I’m missing something obvious. Please tell me what you need to add to this scheme so that it works.

I'm trying to work with `ItemTouchHelper` with two layer layout: one for foreground and another for background. Foreground is swiping fine, but when I click on the delete item of background layout (in any place, including when I click on the button for which the listener is assigned to delete the item), the shifted foreground goes backwards and the deletion does not occur.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code you execute as a reproducible example.